# Azure AAD and automation scripts

Tags: azure, azure-automation

We are developing a PaaS service internal to our company. This means we want to deploy the application with automation scripts. This we know how to do. But our application is required to use AAD (Azure Active Directory). From what we could find online it is only possible to register a app in AAD through the portal with a user that has Admin rights.

The questions we have are:

1. How do we register app(s) in AAD with automation scripts?
2. Does the user running the automation script need Admin rights then?
3. Or does the automation account need admin rights? (Not sure how to assign that)

We have requested help from our Microsoft contact but we are still waiting for a response.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using PowerShell, you can register an application with [New-AzureRmADApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadapplication?view=azurermps-4.0.0).  Elevated privileges are not needed to register the application.